# How to add marker to mapbox using mapboxgl.GeolocateControl

Tags: geolocation, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I would like to add a marker after the user locate himself.

I try to listen to the geolocate event but no marker is added.
How should I proceed ?

```
map.addControl(new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
    positionOptions: {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        watchPosition: true
    }
}));
map.on('geolocate ', () => {
    map.loadImage('images/pin2.png', (error, image, data) => {
        if (error) throw error;
        console.log(data);
        map.addImage('pin2', image);
        map.addLayer({
            "id": "points",
            "type": "symbol",
            "source": {
                "type": "geojson",
                "data": {
                    "type": "FeatureCollection",
                    "features": [{
                        "type": "Feature",
                        "geometry": {
                            "type": "Point",
                            "coordinates": [data.position]
                        }
                    }]
                }
            },
            "layout": {
                "icon-image": "pin2",
                "icon-size": 1
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: First work out if the problem is the geolocate control not firing, or the marker not being visible, or some combination of both. So - does the marker show if you move the code to `on(`load`...)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The geolocate event is actually bound together with the geolocate object not the map object

```
let geolocate = new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
    positionOptions: {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        watchPosition: true
    }
});

map.addControl(geolocate);

geolocate.on('geolocate', (e) => {
    map.loadImage('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/60/Cat_silhouette.svg/400px-Cat_silhouette.svg.png', (error, image) => {
        console.log(e)
        if (error) throw error;
        map.addImage('cat', image);
        map.addLayer({
            "id": "points",
            "type": "symbol",
            "source": {
                "type": "geojson",
                "data": {
                    "type": "FeatureCollection",
                    "features": [{
                        "type": "Feature",
                        "geometry": {
                            "type": "Point",
                            "coordinates": [e.coords.longitude, e.coords.latitude]
                        }
                    }]
                }
            },
            "layout": {
                "icon-image": "cat",
                "icon-size": 0.3
            }
        });
    });
});
```

take a look at the working [JSbin](https://jsbin.com/mimefutuju/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: Mind that geolocation in the browser only works on https domains. When the connection isn't secure, you will not see the Geolocate control on the map.